# How to update database when checkbox in Coldfusion changes?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, database, coldfusion

SO I have created a table where one of the columns is a checkbox called "Arrived" which means that if a client arrived I will check that checkbox and it will update my database (MySql) with the current time.
I know I'll have to use jquery to make an Ajax request to Coldfusion and update the database, BUT I have no idea how to do this.
Can someone give me a small example of how to do this?
Thank you,
HG

**UPDATE**

So I have been doing some stuff on my project and I found a problem.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $(".predicted").on("change",function(event){
                var hora = this.value;
                console.log("Updating time = "+ hora);
                var id = jQuery('input[type=hidden][name=id]').val();;
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                        url: "horaPrevista-update-database.cfc"
                        , type: "POST"
                        , dataType: "json"
                        , data: {"method" : "updatePredicted", "returnFormat": "json", "hora": hora, "id": id}
                    }).done(function(response) {
                        console.log("response", response);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                       console.log("errorMessage",errorMessage);
                    });
               window.location.reload(true);
          });
        });
```

This is my hC-update-database.cfm:

```
<cfcomponent>   
<cfset variables.dsn = "listareservas">

<cffunction name="updatePredicted" returntype="struct" access="remote">
   <cfargument name="hora" type="string" required="true">
   <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="true">

   <cfset local.response = {success=true}>

   <cftry>
       <cfquery datasource="#variables.dsn#">
           UPDATE Reservas
           SET    ReservaTempoPrevisto = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#arguments.hora#"> 
           WHERE  ReservaID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.id#">
       </cfquery>
       <cfcatch>    
           <!--- add handling here... --->
           <cfset local.response = {success=false}>
       </cfcatch>
   </cftry>

   <cfreturn local.response>
</cffunction>
```

And I have a table that is being populated by a query.

```
<cfoutput query="getReservations">
     <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td><input class="form-control predicted" name="predicted" id="ReservaHoraPrevisto" placeholder="HH:MM" value="#timeFormat(ReservaTempoPrevisto,'HH:mm')#">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="#ReservaID#"></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
```

So if for example my query getReservations has 10 records, it will display 10 inputs. The problem is if I try to change the input it always updates in the database the first record that shows up in the table (it always sends the first record value #ReservaID# to hC-update-database.cfm). How do I send the 2 values to the cfc (input and id)?

Comment: Could you please post what you've tried so far? If you're new to S.O., it works differently than a forum :)  Typically, questions contain the code you've tried, the result and any error messages.  For some tips on asking, and to avoid this question being [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no matter which checkbox I check it always updates in the database the first record that shows up in the table

It's because the demo example was designed with a single record in mind. If your form actually deals with multiple records, you'll need to modify the JS and CF code.

Since you're only passing ID's to CF, there's no need for a separate hidden field. Just use the "ReservaID" as the checkbox value. Use the "change" event to update the record when the checkbox state changes. The example below updates the record when a box is checked. Keep in mind a user could uncheck a box - or recheck it. You'll need to decide how those events should be handled on the database side and modify the code accordingly. ex. Do you want to clear the arrival date when unchecked? Update a record with the current date and time if rechecked, etc...?

*Note, my preference is using CFC's for ajax calls. The JS code's similar, just a different URL and data parameters*

```
<!--- manual query for DEMO --->
<cfset getReservations = queryNew("ReservaID","integer",[[1],[2],[3],[4]])>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".arrived").on("change",function(event){
        if (this.checked) {
            var reservaID = this.value;
            console.log("Updating id = "+ reservaID);
            $.ajax({
                url: "SomeComponent.cfc"
                , type: "POST"
                , dataType: "json"
                , data: {"method" : "updateArrival", "returnFormat": "json", "id": reservaID}
            }).done(function(response) {
                console.log("response", response);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
               console.log("errorMessage",errorMessage);
            });
        }
  });
});
</script>


<form>
    <cfoutput query="getReservations">
        <input type="checkbox" class="arrived" name="arrived" value="#ReservaID#" />
    </cfoutput>
</form>
```

On the CF side, create a remote function that accepts a single, numeric ID.

```
<cfcomponent>   
    <cfset variables.dsn = "listareservas">

    <cffunction name="updateArrival" returntype="struct" access="remote">
       <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="true">

       <cfset local.response = {success=true}>

       <cftry>
           <cfquery datasource="#variables.dsn#">
               UPDATE Reservas
               SET    ReservaHoraChegada = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#Now()#"> 
               WHERE  ReservaID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.id#">
           </cfquery>
           <cfcatch>    
               <!--- add handling here... --->
               <cfset local.response = {success=false}>
           </cfcatch>
       </cftry>

       <cfreturn local.response>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the Update button? I have 2 reasons: One is because I don't want to click on a button for it to update the database. I want to check the checkbox and automatically update the database. And second this will update the arrival time of records that might have been updated before (imagine I select one record and then I click update, and then some time after I want to update another record, that will affect the record I previously updated and I don't want that).

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer. Keep in mind a user could uncheck a box - or recheck it. You'll need to decide how those events should be handled on the database side and modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Work perfectly! Regarding the case of a user unchecking or recheking a box, I'll have to think about what I want to do with that. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Another question: What if instead of a checkbox, I have an input field where I'm expecting a time (HH:mm). The value on that input type will be the time the user chose. So how would I send the id to the JS and consequently the cfc?

Comment: Textboxes have different events. Hooking into the onBlur event might work. Though, that's a different question, so best to open a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

**Form template:**

form-template.cfm

```
<cfparam name="url.clientid" default="0">

<cfoutput>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

          jQuery("input[type=checkbox][name=arrived]").on('click',function(event){
            var currentObj = jQuery(event.currentTarget);
            if(currentObj.prop("checked") === true){
              var ajaxurl = "ajax-update-database.cfm?clientid=" + jQuery('input[type=hidden][name=clientid]').val();
              jQuery.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl
              })
              .done(function(response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log("obj",obj);
              })
              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log("errorMessage",errorMessage);
              });
            }
          });

        });

      </script>

    </head>

    <body>

      <form>
        <label for="arrived">Arrived</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="arrived">
        <input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="#url.clientid#">
      </form>

    </body>
  </html>

</cfoutput>
```

**Ajax template:**

ajax-update-database.cfm

```
<cfparam name="url.clientid" default="0">
<cfparam name="variables.response" default="#StructNew()#">

<cfset variables.response['error'] = "">

<cfif Val(url.clientid)>

  <cftry>
    <cfquery datasource="yourDSN">
      UPDATE yourDBTable
      SET Arrived = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint" value="1">, Submission_date = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#Now()#"> 
      WHERE ClientID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.clientid#">
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch>
      <cfset variables.response['error'] = "An error occurred whilst trying to update the database">
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>

</cfif>

<cfoutput>
#SerializeJSON(variables.response)#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: @Hugo Gaspar I hope this helps Hugo?

Comment: To make it easier for others to understand, could you include an example of what the accompanying `<form>` looks like? While making an ajax call to .cfm script is valid, it's a lot more temperamental than invoking a CFC which is often confusing to those learning ajax calls. Consider using a CFC instead. Invoking it with `returnFormat=json` to automatically serialize objects and `dataType: 'json'` to automatically deserialize the response. Side note, it's good practice to scope all variables.

Comment: @Ageax RE: ajax to cfc: I guess this is your opinion. I find making an ajax request to a template easier to understand, especially for beginners. I agree that my variables should be scoped. Good call. I will update now & add the form part as well, although I assume from the question, the OP has already got this part covered.

Comment: @Ageax Although, I am not entirely sure whether the OP is interested anymore?

Comment: The problem with .cfm's is they're brittle. When it comes to returning JSON, something as small the wrong white space or enabling debugging can break it, causing you to chase your tail for an hour wondering why.  CFC are far better at controlling output, and they're more flexible. Example, no need to serialize manually, just add a flag `returnFormat=json`, etc.. That makes for more modular code.

Comment: "although I assume from the question, the OP has already got this part covered." Could be, though I was also thinking of others reading this thread in the future. Clear and complete examples are like gold when you're learning something new :)

Comment: Fair enough, although I have never had a problem with SerializeJson(), so far. The other reason I am using a template here, is because from the OPs question, I am assuming he is new to CF. Adding a CFC into the mix, might cause problems, although I agree that, in general, CFCs are more modular.

Comment: Also, for anyone, who has a problem with 'booleans' & SerializeJson(), this is a great library that I often use, written by the great Ben Nadel: https://github.com/bennadel/JsonSerializer.cfc/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am working on it, as soon as I finish it or have any questions I'll post here!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was not able to get the example by SOS to work.  However, the example by Charles Robertson worked for me.